# modrewrite, ampersand in variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ampersand

I have a site with venues like AT&T Park.
The links for this page should be: /venue.php?venue=at-and-t+park

Using htaccess, I've cleaned them up to look like.

```
RewriteRule venue/([^/]+)/{0,1}$ venue.php?venue=$1 [QSA]
```

So: `/venue/AT-and-T+Park/`

Problem:
Somewhere google is finding and indexing links that look like this, which return as 403 errors. It's an ampersand issue.

```
/venue/AT&T+Park/
```

Is there way for me to change my rewrite rule to look for this oddball `&` and convert it to `-and-`?

Comment: Do you have links on your website using the "&" instead of the mentioned replaced "and"?
Also if it is just one link, you can have google remove it in the webmaster tool found at http://google.com/webmasters/

Comment: I havent been able to track down any links on the site that use &. Though one may exist somewhere. Still searching. There are actually a lot of link variations, and think will likely be a repeat issue even if I remove the url from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a rule before your current rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /$1-and-$2 [L,R=301]
```